# Tag list asp.net or javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, tags

I would like to add a taglist in my webapplication. I have a list of tags with an integer indicating each tag's popularity.

Many web applications display the tags and their popularity using a different font-size.

Because it is so broadly used, I would think that their is a plugin out there that displays this.

An example of what I mean by a taglist can be found here: 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/

Does anyone of you know some kind of plugin that deals with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to create is called a "Tag Cloud".

There is a control/tutorial available on CodeProject that can be found at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/cloud.aspx

or Four Guys from Rolla has a tutorial that can be found at
https://web.archive.org/web/20210616112719/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102506-1.aspx